# Using Yii CjuiSortable to store weight in database

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii

I am trying to create a list of sortable items and store their weight in the database, I am having trouble sending the sorted data to the controller, here is what I have done so far:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
     $items[$category->id] = $category->title;
 }
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiSortable', array(
        'id'=>'items',
        'items'=>$items,
        'options'=>array(
                'cursor'=>'n-resize',
                'update'=>"js:function(){
                        $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '{$this->createUrl('site/menuArrange')}',
                                data: {'items[]':$(this).sortable('toArray')},
                        });
                }",
        ),
));
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function actionMenuArrange()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['items']) && is_array($_POST['items'])) {
               foreach($_POST['items'] as $index=>$id){
                    $item = Item::model()->findByPk($id);
                    $item->order = $index;
                    $item->save();
                }
            }
            $this->render('menu_arrange',array(
            ));
    }
```

can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: so what is your problem. Is it related to getting the sorted list or it is related actually  to the sorting not working issue?

Comment: @Runcorn thanks for your reply, it is related to getting the sorted list into the controller, sorting is working fine.

Comment: So did you checked the Request sent in the AJAX call. Use the browser console to view if data is present in `item[]` or not.Just to be sure.

Comment: Ok items[] could be the issue , Just use :   `data: {items:$(this).sortable('toArray')},`